# jThree.jsのgomlを使用せず、`THREE.MMD.VMD`を使用してアニメーションさせたい

Tags: coffeescript, three.js

下記のコードのように`THREE.SCENE`インスタンスに、`THREE.MMD.PMX`インスタンスからメッシュを生成して追加したところ表示はできたのですが、`THREE.MMD.VMD`インスタンスを使用してアニメーションさせる手順が分かりません。

`goml`の`<mmd model="foo.pmx" motion="bar.vmd" onLoad="parent.jThree.MMD.play(true);"/>`と同等の処理を、プログラマティックに行う方法はありますか？

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/3acd7a85f179a3ab02bae3c563e00ca90801b3b6/lib/jThree.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/3acd7a85f179a3ab02bae3c563e00ca90801b3b6/lib/jThree.Stats.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/3acd7a85f179a3ab02bae3c563e00ca90801b3b6/lib/jThree.MMD.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/3acd7a85f179a3ab02bae3c563e00ca90801b3b6/lib/jThree.Trackball.js"></script>
<script src="http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/coffeescript">
  # Private
  camera= null
  renderer= null
  trackball= null
  
  resize= ->
    camera= new THREE.PerspectiveCamera 45, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000
    camera.position.set 0, 20, 70
    renderer.setSize innerWidth,innerHeight
  
    trackball= new THREE.TrackballControls camera
  
  # Main
  window.addEventListener 'resize',->
    return unless renderer
    resize()
  
  # document.addEventListener 'DOMContentLoaded',->
  requestAnimationFrame ->
    scene= new THREE.Scene
  
    directionalLight= new THREE.DirectionalLight '#ffffff', 1
    directionalLight.position.set 0, 7, 10
    scene.add directionalLight
  
    geometry= new THREE.CubeGeometry 50, 1, 50
    material= new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial {color:'#999999'}
    cube= new THREE.Mesh geometry, material
    cube.position.set 0, -.5, 0
    scene.add cube
  
    pmx= new THREE.MMD.PMX
    pmx.load 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/3acd7a85f179a3ab02bae3c563e00ca90801b3b6/example/miku/index.pmx',(pmx)->
      pmx.createMesh {},(mesh)->
        scene.add mesh
  
        vmd= new THREE.MMD.VMD
        vmd.load 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/3acd7a85f179a3ab02bae3c563e00ca90801b3b6/example/miku/im5066365.vmd',(vmd)->
          cAnimation= vmd.generateCameraAnimation
          lAnimation= vmd.generateLightAnimation
          mAnimation= vmd.generateMorphAnimation pmx
          sAnimation= vmd.generateSkinAnimation pmx
  
          # do staff?
          
          requestAnimationFrame -> render()
          render= ->
            trackball.update() if trackball
            renderer.render scene,camera
  
            requestAnimationFrame render
  
    renderer=
      if window.WebGLRenderingContext
        new THREE.WebGLRenderer
      else
        new THREE.CanvasRenderer
  
    resize()
  
    document.body.appendChild renderer.domElement
  
</script>
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #abc;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

静止して立ったままのポーズで分かりにくいですが、まばたきや動きのある.vmdを使用しても動作するようなコードが用意できたので、自己解決とさせて頂きます。

> 参考：[jThree.MMD.js…`<goml>`を使用せずアニメーションさせたい · Issue #2 · j3-jp/jThree](https://github.com/j3-jp/jThree/issues/2)

```html
<style>
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #abc;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/e19f703b64e1f088aa8be484e75ded9a698489e3/lib/jThree.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/e19f703b64e1f088aa8be484e75ded9a698489e3/lib/jThree.Stats.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/e19f703b64e1f088aa8be484e75ded9a698489e3/lib/jThree.MMD.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/e19f703b64e1f088aa8be484e75ded9a698489e3/lib/jThree.Trackball.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/stats.js/6b5cba034e5a30941b01da3fa785da49338fa676/build/stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
<script type="text/coffeescript">
# Private
camera= null
renderer= null
trackball= null

resize= ->
  camera= new THREE.PerspectiveCamera 45, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000
  camera.position.set 0, 20, 70
  renderer.setSize innerWidth,innerHeight

  trackball= new THREE.TrackballControls camera

# Main
window.addEventListener 'resize',->
  return unless renderer
  resize()

# document.addEventListener 'DOMContentLoaded',->
requestAnimationFrame ->
  stats= new Stats
  stats.domElement.style.position= 'absolute'
  stats.domElement.style.left= '0px'
  stats.domElement.style.top= '0px'

  scene= new THREE.Scene

  directionalLight= new THREE.DirectionalLight '#ffffff', 1
  directionalLight.position.set 0, 7, 10
  scene.add directionalLight

  geometry= new THREE.CubeGeometry 50, 1, 50
  material= new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial {color:'#999'}
  cube= new THREE.Mesh geometry, material
  cube.position.set 0, -.5, 0
  scene.add cube

  endless= yes
  pmx= new THREE.MMD.PMX
  pmx.load 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/e19f703b64e1f088aa8be484e75ded9a698489e3/example/miku/index.pmx',(pmx)->
    pmx.createMesh {},(mesh)->
      vmd= new THREE.MMD.VMD
      vmd.load 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/59naga/j3/e19f703b64e1f088aa8be484e75ded9a698489e3/example/miku/im5066365.vmd',(vmd)->
      # vmd.load 'bower_components/j3/example/miku/im5066365.vmd',(vmd)->
        hasAd= pmx.bones.some (bone)-> bone.additionalTransform
        addTrans= new THREE.MMD.MMDAddTrans pmx, mesh if hasAd

        mAnimation= vmd.generateMorphAnimation pmx
        morph= new THREE.MMD.MMDMorph mesh, mAnimation if mAnimation
        morph.play endless if morph

        sAnimation= vmd.generateSkinAnimation pmx
        skin= new THREE.MMD.MMDSkin mesh, sAnimation if sAnimation
        skin.play endless if skin

        delta= 0
        if mesh.geometry.MMDIKs.length
          ik= new THREE.MMD.MMDIK mesh
          physi= new THREE.MMD.MMDPhysi mesh if window.Ammo

          renderer.renderPluginsPre.unshift
            render: ->
              if window.Ammo
                physi.preSimulate delta if physi
                THREE.MMD.btWorld.stepSimulation delta
                physi.postSimulate delta if physi

        scene.add mesh

        resetBone= ->
          bones= mesh.bones;
          for bone,i in mesh.geometry.bones
            mesh.bones[i].position.set　bone.pos[0], bone.pos[1], bone.pos[2]
            mesh.bones[i].quaternion.set bone.rotq[0], bone.rotq[1], bone.rotq[2], bone.rotq[3]

        clock= new THREE.Clock
        requestAnimationFrame -> render()
        render= ->
          delta= clock.getDelta()
          stats.begin()

          resetBone()

          morph.update delta if morph
          skin.update delta if skin
          ik.update delta if ik
          addTrans.update delta if addTrans

          trackball.update() if trackball

          renderer.render scene,camera

          stats.end()
          requestAnimationFrame render

  renderer=
    if window.WebGLRenderingContext
      new THREE.WebGLRenderer
    else
      new THREE.CanvasRenderer

  resize()

  document.body.appendChild renderer.domElement
  document.body.appendChild stats.domElement
</script>
```